# How to include an html file in another html file using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a **index.html** file and another **topBar.html** file and I want to include that file in my **index.html**.

My directory structure is like below:

```
mainfolder/
    scripts/
    views/
        topBar.html
    index.html
```

Here is the code that I tried

```
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <div ng-include="'views/topBar.html'"></div>
 </div>
```

But nothing is being displayed and it gives me error in the console

> angular.js:12701 Failed to load
>   file:'path' Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Comment: The error message says it all. Don't try to run your angular **web** application from the file system. Run it by serving the files from a **web** server, over http.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have written your code in yur code editior and testing your page in your browser without using any server then this error comes. You can test plain html css in browser that will work fine , but when you craete something more than just html , css then that gives error . A server has to be used for that .many web browsers are programed to watch for cross site attacks, and will block requests. You don't want anyone being able to read your hard drive from your web browser.

**Solution :**

Install a local server and then run your application on server.